# Node.js - Empty file written, but why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, dom-events, nodes

**TL;DR** Why is the first file written, but the remaining files empty?

I have a for loop in Node.js that loops an array list of file strings. Each string represents a different file in it's respective directory. The array contains three values that are needed to create three seperate files. After the first file is created and written to, the second and third files are created but remain empty. Below is the short hand version of the code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
for(i in file_tree) {

  fp = fs.createWriteStream(file_tree[i]);

  for(i in data) {
    fp.write(data[i]+'\n', function (err) { if(error) throw err;});
  }

} // end for loop - file_tree
```

====== SOLUTION =====

```
file_tree = [
    pn+ '/theme/file1',
    pn+ '/theme/file2',
  pn+ '/theme/file3',
];

for(i in file_tree) {

    file_name = file_tree[i];
    fp = fs.createWriteStream(file_name);

    data = [];
    switch(file_name) {
        case pn+ "/theme/file1":
                    --- snip --
            break;

        //
        // ERROR BEGINS HERE : Notice no '/' prefix
        //
        case pn+ "theme/file2":
            --snip--
            break;

        default: show(help);
    }

    for(i in data) {
            fp.write(data[i]+'\n', function(err) { if (err) throw err; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if(error)`, you probably mean `if(err)`. You also use `i` twice, but that shouldn't have any side effects. With these changes, I still can't reproduce the effect. With [my demo program](https://gist.github.com/2134731), both files get written and are identical. Can you provide a [*complete*](http://sscce.org) example? Does the problem occur on your system with [my demo program](https://gist.github.com/2134731)?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was missing a trailing slash in the long form version of the code. Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you for showing interest.

Comment: @phihag - Good catch. I wrote incorrect code trying to give an example. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Would you mind writing an answer yourself and detailing what you changed? That way, anyone else with the same or a similar problem also benefits from this question. Thanks!

Comment: file_tree = [
     pn+ '/theme/file1',
     pn+ '/theme/file2',
      pn+ '/theme/file3',
    ];

    for(i in file_tree) {
 
     file_name = file_tree[i];
     fp = fs.createWriteStream(file_name);

     data = [];
     switch(file_name) {
      case pn+ "/theme/file1":
     --- snip --
       break;

      //
      // ERROR BEGINS HERE : Notice no '/' prefix
      //
      case pn+ "theme/file2":
       --snip--
       break;

      default: show(help);
     }

     for(i in data) {
       fp.write(data[i]+'\n', function(err) { if (err) throw err; });
     }
    }

Comment: I have to wait 3 hours before I can answer my self because I'm a new member. I'll respond when able.

Comment: No problem, I made the comment into an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9790828/35070). It's marked [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), so [everybody with 100+ rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

`data` has not been properly initialized. The previous code was:

```
file_tree = [ pn+ '/theme/file1', pn+ '/theme/file2', pn+ '/theme/file3'];
for(i in file_tree) {
    file_name = file_tree[i];
    fp = fs.createWriteStream(file_name);
    data = [];
    switch(file_name) {
    case pn+ "/theme/file1":
        data.push("content-1");
        break;
    case pn+ "theme/file2": // <-- error
        data.push("content-2");
        break;
    default: show(help);
    }
    for(i in data) {
        fp.write(data[i]+'\n', function(err) { if (err) throw err; });
    }
}
```

Since the case statement was missing a slash, it didn't match, and therefore, `data` was empty.